# Matlab plot lines showing through fill area

Tags: matlab, fill, edges

I've written a program that creates a grid of hexagons, some black, some white. This is done randomly. I then choose randomly a subset of hexagons on the edges of which to place red diamonds. This script is designed to build pretend rock microstructures with grains (hexagons) and pore spaces (diamonds) for materials modeling. I'm using the fill() command to create each shape. The problem is that when I fill in the red diamonds, the edge of the hexagon beneath it is still showing through. I tried to post an image, but since this is my first time posting, it won't let me. I can email though, if anyone wants to see.

So to create the black hexagons:

```
h= fill(hexXY(i,j,1)+vx,hexXY(i,j,2)+vy,'k');

set(h,'edgecolor','k')
```

where the hexXY matrix holds x and y coordinates for the center of the hexagon, which added to the vx and vy arrays gives the vertices of each point on the hexagon. I then do the same thing with the diamonds:

```
h=fill(hexXY(i,j,1)+dvx,hexXY(i,j,2)+dvy,'r');

set(h,'edgecolor','r')
```

But, as I said, the black edges of the hexagons show through the red. I provided the vertices in order like you would draw them, though I don't think that should matter. I tried uistack and using patch, but neither worked for me. I can't set the hexagon edge color to none, because I have also have white hexagons, and if I set the background color to black I'd get black lines between the white hexagons. I removed have to remove the edge from either black or white hexagons, because where the two touch, the edges give messy pixelation.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get the red diamonds filled in properly?

EDIT: I didn't mention before, that this only occurs while saving the figure.You can't see it in the figure window. I've tried using print() and hgexport(), and changing the renderer, to no avail. Here is a small example with numbers pulled from my code to run:

```
hold on
v1=[0.3929 0.4107 0.3929 0.3571 0.3393 0.3571];
v2=[0.6907 0.6598 0.6288 0.6288 0.6598 0.6907];
h= fill(v1,v2,'k');
set(h,'edgecolor','k')

v3=[0.3750 0.3929 0.3750 0.3571 0.3750];
v4=[0.6366 0.6288 0.6211 0.6288 0.6366];
h=fill(v3,v4,'r');
set(h,'edgecolor','r')

set(gca,'position',[0 0 1 1],'units','normalized')
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','Inches','PaperPosition',[0 0 5 5]);
hgexport(gcf, 'test', hgexport('factorystyle'), 'Format', 'tiff','Resolution',600);
```

Here is the image saved with `hgexport`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your edges transparent:

```
set(h,'edgealpha',0)
```

---

Something weird is causing the original problem. If the commands are kept simple, everything appears fine:

```
h1= fill([1,2,3,3,2,1],[2,4,3,2,0,1],'m');
set(h1,'edgecolor','m')

hold on
h2= fill([2,3,2.5],[2,1,pi],'g');
set(h2,'edgecolor','g')
```

But the background edge moves forward when the foreground triangle is changed.

```
set(h2,'edgealpha',0) % an example of what can cause the problem to appear.
```

I don't know what's causing that.

Comment: Unfortunately, making the edges transparent doesn't solve the problem. I also didn't note, I should have, that this doesn't appear in the figure window, the issue only occurs when saving the figure. I've tried using print() and hgexport(), and changing the renderer, and that doesn't help either. I don't seem to show any issues with the example code that you posted, it isn't doing the same thing.

Comment: When I use my formatting code, with your example, you can see the line appear through the fill.

Comment: Oh, for some reason the lines issue I was concerned about stopped happening. I am not sure why it went away, or I guess it's smart enough to do it right when I remove the edgecolor of both b and w hexagons. Or it's bc I'm on a different computer than before. Well, I guess I didn't even need to ask this whole question then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it worked itself out, though it'd be nice to know why! From the inconsistencies, it seems like a bug on Mathwork's end.

Answer (score 1):

If `set(h,'edgealpha',0)` does not work (as suggested by *@user1739107*), you may try `set(h,'edgecolor','none')`.

On OSX R2012b, both solutions work fine.

Comment: I can't set the edge color on the hexagons to none because I would get white lines showing in between the black hexagons. And I can't change the background color to black, because then I would get black lines showing through between white hexagons....I'm using R2013b, so maybe that's related.

Comment: you may try playing with [hg2](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update/), or define patch in the `z` axis (red on top).

Comment: Oops I meant to post the comment on the other answer on this one. My issue went away and simply removing the edge color ended up working. Thank you for your help!